# What is the impact of deleting /etc/rc.d and /etc/rc0.d?

Tags: command, rm, delete, deleted-files

I am relatively new to black-screen Os-es (*nix)
I was given few commands to run on Linux:

- remove etc/rc.d/rc0.d remove only logscan, procscan and gpp

I got confused and did:

1. `rm -rf rc.d`
2. `rm -rf rc0.d` as a result init.d also got deleted.**

Later, I copied the `rc.d` folder from another server but there are several softlinks and the whole folder structure was lost, no softlinks only files were there.

What is the impact or effects of removing `/etc/rc.d` and `/etc/rc0.d`? How is it related to the `init.d` file? Can we restore these files (`rc.d` & `rc0.d`)? 
Can we perhaps copy them  from another server and place them under `/etc`? Will that help? Does restarting help?

Comment: Is this a systemd operating system?  Your operating system isn't Linux.  That is [an operating system kernel](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/operating-system-nut-metaphor.html).  Your operating system will be something like (for examples) Arch Linux, or Ubuntu, or Fedora, or OpenSUSE.  Without knowing that, answerers cannot know how problematic the situation is, or what the names of the tools for correcting the situation even are.

Comment: Hi @terdon or someone please find the OS details.   
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 
(mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) 
(gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) 
#1 SMP Wed Oct 26 10:25:23 EDT 2016

Please help me!!

Comment: To find the operating system and version, try any of the following commands: `cat /etc/*-release` `hostnamectl` `lsb_release -a` `cat /etc/issue`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I have found the OS Version ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 
(mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) 
(gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) 
#1 SMP Wed Oct 26 10:25:23 EDT 2016

Comment: @JdeBP or NasirRiley Please help this is an emergency. please help me in recovering these files or tell me about the side effects or impacts of removing /etc/rc.d file or folder.We have twin servers so can we copy and make it work?? Please help.

Comment: As you are running RHEL 6, the service files are in those directories. You're not going to notice anything as their processes are already started but if you reboot or shut the machine down, it's not going to come back because the services that it needs to run aren't going to start. You can attempt to copy those directories from another machine as the basic services will be there but anything else will need to be reinstalled or reconfigured.

Comment: @NasirRiley  it's Red Hat 4.4.7-17. So getting back the basic services without any problem would be fine.. other things can be reinstalled. so can this be done without any problem for next reboot? sorry am bothering you much.. but this is a hectic situation.

Comment: `Red Hat 4.4.7-17` is just the version of the GCC compiler used to build your RHEL6 standard kernel version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64. The `el6` in the kernel version indicates you're using RHEL/CentOS/OEL/ScientificLinux 6.x... and the kernel patch level -642 indicates the patch level of the whole OS is probably about RHEL 6.8 or so.

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL 6, `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` is the actual location of the SysVinit-style startup/shutdown scripts. `/etc/init.d` is a symbolic link to it.

The `/etc/rc.d/rc[0-6].d` directories should only contain symbolic links pointing to scripts in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`. There is also a set of symbolic links at `/etc/rc[0-6].d` pointing to the respective directories in `/etc/rc.d/`.

The best option would be to recover these directories from a backup that was originally taken from the same server, as it ensures that you will have the exact same configuration as before.

But if you have multiple servers configured the same way (=  the same RPMs installed, the same services running), then you could have pretty good (but not necessarily perfect) results by copying the directories.

I would definitely suggest copying `/etc/rc.d/rc`, `/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit` from the other server first, as they are likely to be unchanged between servers. Without these scripts, the server will certainly crash to single user mode very early in the boot process, which may make further repairs more inconvenient.

`/etc/rc.d/rc.local` might or might not be modified by your local administrators; by default it does nothing, but it's better to have it exist. So copy it too, but if it has non-default contents, make sure the content is applicable.

You could then copy the contents of `/etc/rc.d/init.d` from a server that is configured the same as the damaged system, then use these commands to restore the default symbolic links for the scripts:

```
cd /etc/rc.d/init.d
for i in *; do chkconfig --add $i; done
```

This will restore the *factory default* enabled/disabled configuration of various services; after this, you should run `chkconfig --list` on both the damaged server and on the other identically-configured server, and use `chkconfig <service name> on` / `chkconfig <service name> off` commands to adjust the enabled/disabled state of various services to match what the other identically-configured server actually has (or whatever makes sense regarding the damaged server's purpose, if the other server is not exactly identical).

You can then use `rpm -Va | grep /etc/rc.d/init.d` to verify that all the scripts for software installed from RPMs are present. It will list any scripts that are missing or modified from their default state as delivered within the RPMs. If some scripts are missing, `yum reinstall <package name>` might be an easy way to fix them.

If you have some third-party software that is not installed from RPM packages, you will need to review their installation instructions and check if they have start-up scripts that will have to be replaced manually.